# Drawing a tikz tree above a tikz-dependency tree with same leaves

Tags: tikz-pgf, linguistics, trees

I would like to achieve the following goal:

I have two different kind of trees that I would like to merge :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  shapes,%
  arrows,%
  positioning,%
  calc,%
  automata%
}
\definecolor{pf7}{RGB}{166, 118, 29}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level/.style={sibling distance=2cm,
    level distance = 1cm}
]
    \tikzset{level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm}}
    \node {S}
    child{
        node (np) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{NP}}}
        child {
            node {D} child{node {The}}
        }
        child[red] {
            node {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{N}}} child[black]{node {cat}}
        }
    }
child{
    node (vp) {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{VP}}}
    child[blue] {
        node {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{V}}} child[black]{node {sat}}
    }
    child[blue] {
        node {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{PP}}}
        child {
            node {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{P}}} child[black]{node {on}}
        }
        child[black] {
            node {NP}
            child {
                node {D} child{node {the}}
            }
            child {
                node {N} child{node {mat}}
            }
        }
    }
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Constituent tree]

and a dependency tree :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  shapes,%
  arrows,%
  positioning,%
  calc,%
  automata%
}
\definecolor{pf7}{RGB}{166, 118, 29}

\begin{document}
\begin{dependency}
        \begin{deptext}[column sep=3em]
            \textbf{The} \& \textbf{cat} \& \textbf{sat} \& \textbf{on} \& \textbf{the} \& \textbf{mat} \\
            \textbf{1}    \& \textbf{2}     \& \textbf{3} \& \textbf{4}    \& \textbf{5}     \& \textbf{6} \\
        \end{deptext}
        \depedge[edge below]{3}{2}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{nsubj}}
        \depedge[edge below]{4}{6}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{pobj}}
        \depedge[edge below]{3}{4}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{prep}}
        \depedge[edge below]{2}{1}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{det}}
        \depedge[edge below]{6}{5}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{det}}
    \end{dependency}
\end{document}
```

[image: Dependency tree]

So far I managed to get this, bu the tikz upper tree is not well-aligned (as it was) and I don't know how to achieve this.

```
\begin{dependency}
    \begin{deptext}[column sep=3em]
        \textbf{The} \& \textbf{cat} \& \textbf{sat} \& \textbf{on} \& \textbf{the} \& \textbf{mat} \\
        \textbf{1}    \& \textbf{2}     \& \textbf{3} \& \textbf{4}    \& \textbf{5}     \& \textbf{6} \\
    \end{deptext}

    \node[yshift=7cm] {S}
    child{
        node (np) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{NP}}}
        child {
            node {D} child{node at ($(\wordref{1}{1})$) {}}
        }
        child[red] {
            node {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{N}}}
            child[black]{node at($(\wordref{1}{2})$) {}}
        }
    }
    child{
        node (vp) {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{VP}}}
        child[blue] {
            node {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{V}}}
            child[black]{node at($(\wordref{1}{3})$) {}}
        }
        child[blue] {
            node {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{PP}}}
            child {
                node {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{P}}}
                child[black]{node at($(\wordref{1}{4})$) {}}
            }
            child[black] {
                node {NP}
                child {
                    node {D} child{node at($(\wordref{1}{5})$) {}}
                }
                child {
                    node {N} child{node at($(\wordref{1}{6})$) {}}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ;


    \depedge[edge below]{3}{2}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{nsubj}}
    \depedge[edge below]{4}{6}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{pobj}}
    \depedge[edge below]{3}{4}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{prep}}
    \depedge[edge below]{2}{1}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{det}}
    \depedge[edge below]{6}{5}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{det}}
\end{dependency}
```

[image: Merged trees]

If somebody can help me, it would be very nice,

Have a nice day.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  shapes,%
  arrows,%
  positioning,%
  calc,%
  automata%
}
\definecolor{pf7}{RGB}{166, 118, 29}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level/.style={sibling distance=2cm,
    level distance = 1cm}
]
    \tikzset{level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm}}
    \node {S}
    child{
        node (np) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{NP}}}
        child {
            node (d1) {D}
        }
        child[red] {
            node (n1) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{N}}}
        }
    }
child{
    node (vp) {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{VP}}}
    child[blue] {
        node (v) {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{V}}}
    }
    child[blue] {
        node {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{PP}}}
        child {
            node (p) {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{P}}}
        }
        child[black] {
            node {NP}
            child {
                node (d2) {D}
            }
            child {
                node (n2) {N}
            }
        }
    }
}
;
\begin{scope}[shift={(1cm,-2.2in)}]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=3em]
            \textbf{The} \& \textbf{cat} \& \textbf{sat} \& \textbf{on} \& \textbf{the} \& \textbf{mat} \\
            \textbf{1}    \& \textbf{2}     \& \textbf{3} \& \textbf{4}    \& \textbf{5}     \& \textbf{6} \\
        \end{deptext}
        \depedge[edge below]{3}{2}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{nsubj}}
        \depedge[edge below]{4}{6}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{pobj}}
        \depedge[edge below]{3}{4}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{prep}}
        \depedge[edge below]{2}{1}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{det}}
        \depedge[edge below]{6}{5}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{det}}
\end{scope}
 \draw [->, very thick, red] (d1) -- (\wordref{1}{1});
 \draw [->, very thick, red] (n1) -- (\wordref{1}{2});
 \draw [->, very thick, red] (v) -- (\wordref{1}{3});
 \draw [->, very thick, red] (p) -- (\wordref{1}{4});
 \draw [->, very thick, red] (d2) -- (\wordref{1}{5});
 \draw [->, very thick, red] (n2) -- (\wordref{1}{6});
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I have removed the last `child`ren and added a label to the `node`s and then using `\wordref` if dependency, draw the edge. Aligning them may be done manually.

Your code can be modified like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  shapes,%
  arrows,%
  positioning,%
  calc,%
  automata%
}
\definecolor{pf7}{RGB}{166, 118, 29}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level/.style={sibling distance=2cm,
    level distance = 1cm},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm}
]
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1cm,0in)}]
    \begin{deptext}[column sep=3em]
        \textbf{The} \& \textbf{cat} \& \textbf{sat} \& \textbf{on} \& \textbf{the} \& \textbf{mat} \\
        \textbf{1}    \& \textbf{2}     \& \textbf{3} \& \textbf{4}    \& \textbf{5}     \& \textbf{6} \\
    \end{deptext}
    \end{scope}

    \node[yshift=5cm] {S}
    child{
        node (np) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{NP}}}
        child {
            node {D} child{node at ($(\wordref{1}{1})$) {}}
        }
        child[red] {
            node {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{N}}}
            child[black]{node at($(\wordref{1}{2})$) {}}
        }
    }
    child{
        node (vp) {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{VP}}}
        child[blue] {
            node {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{V}}}
            child[black]{node at($(\wordref{1}{3})$) {}}
        }
        child[blue] {
            node {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{PP}}}
            child {
                node {\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{P}}}
                child[black]{node at($(\wordref{1}{4})$) {}}
            }
            child[black] {
                node {NP}
                child {
                    node {D} child{node at($(\wordref{1}{5})$) {}}
                }
                child {
                    node {N} child{node at($(\wordref{1}{6})$) {}}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ;


    \depedge[edge below]{3}{2}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{nsubj}}
    \depedge[edge below]{4}{6}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{pobj}}
    \depedge[edge below]{3}{4}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{prep}}
    \depedge[edge below]{2}{1}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{det}}
    \depedge[edge below]{6}{5}{\bf\textcolor{pf7}{det}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Corentin You are welcome :)

Answer (score 12):

Here's a `forest` approach I ought not have spent time playing with (even if it is Saturday!) ;).

What I like about this method is the automatic placement of the words and their alignment with their parent nodes. However, the drawing of the dependencies underneath is rather clunky and probably fragile.

Basically, when you get to the last node of the syntax tree, you say `word={}{}` where the first argument is the word and the second is a unique label. (This is necessary in case you have identical words in the same sentence.)

After the tree is complete, but before ending the `forest`, you can then use the `pic` `depedge={}{}{}{}` to draw the dependencies. This takes 4 arguments: the originating node, the terminating node, whether you want to be 1 layer down from the word or 2, and what the content of the label in the middle should be.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \newcounter{word}
  \forestset{
    colour group/.style={#1, edge=#1, for parent={#1}},
    word/.style n args=2{
      append={
          [{#1\\\stepcounter{word}\theword},
            name=#2,
            tier=word,
            font=\bfseries,
            align=center,
            inner ysep=1pt,
            for descendants={l=-2pt},
            [, name=#2-dep1, tier=dep1, dep node, edge path={\relax}
              [, name=#2-dep2, tier=dep2, dep node, edge path={\relax}
              ]
            ]
          ]
        },
    },
  }
  \tikzset{
    dep node/.style={shape=coordinate},
    dep type/.style={midway, fill=white, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=.75pt, text=orange!75!black, outer sep=0pt, draw, minimum height=8pt},
    pics/depedge/.style n args={4}{
      code={
        \ifnum#3=1
          \draw [->, rounded corners=2pt, pic actions] ({$(#1)!.075!(#2)$} |- #1.south) -- ($(#1-dep#3)!.125!(#2-dep#3)$) -- node [dep type] {#4} ($(#2-dep#3)!.125!(#1-dep#3)$) -- ({$(#2)!.075!(#1)$} |- #1.south);
        \else\ifnum#3=2
          \draw [->, rounded corners=2pt, pic actions] (#1.south) -- ($(#1-dep#3)!.075!(#2-dep#3)$) -- node [dep type] {#4} ($(#2-dep#3)!.075!(#1-dep#3)$) -- (#2.south);
        \fi\fi
      },
    },
  }

  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      s sep+=10pt,
    }
    [S
      [NP
        [D, word={The}{the1}
        ]
        [N, colour group=red, word={cat}{cat}
        ]
      ]
      [VP
        [V, colour group=blue, word={sat}{sat}
        ]
        [PP, colour group=blue
          [P, colour group=blue, word={on}{on}
          ]
          [NP
            [D, word={the}{the2}
            ]
            [N, word={mat}{mat}
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    \pic {depedge={cat}{the1}{1}{det}};
    \pic {depedge={mat}{the2}{1}{det}};
    \pic {depedge={sat}{cat}{1}{nsubj}};
    \pic {depedge={sat}{on}{1}{prep}};
    \pic {depedge={on}{mat}{2}{pobj}};
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest dependencies]

Comment: @Corentin Thanks. I'm sure there must be a better way to add the dependency paths but I have no idea what at the moment!