# Brat for NLP in latex

Tags: diagrams, linguistics

I was wondering if there is any package for text annotation in Latex like [Brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/examples.html#annotation-examples).

This is the kind of result I would like to obtain in a figure:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve that by using brat or some other libraries, without drawing it with inkscape and converting it to svg, or with tikz?

All solutions and hints accepted!

Comment: There is probably a linguistics package about that can do something like this, but I honestly don't see why TikZ wouldn't be an option. Done right, it's very powerful.

Comment: I've changed the tags accordingly and if you search for them you'll see many examples e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233055/drawing-a-tikz-tree-above-a-tikz-dependency-tree-with-same-leaves The dedicated package is `tikz-dependency`

Comment: Marginally related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183032/sentence-diagramming

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, since I didn't know the `tikz-dependency` package percusse cited in his comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{dependency}[label style={draw=white}]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=1em,
row 2/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!16, draw=white}}]
PRP \& VBD \& NNP \& NNP \&[2.5em] POS \& NN \&[-.5em] .\\[1.6ex]
It \& was \& Jesse \& Bear \& 's \& birthday \& . \\
\end{deptext}
\depedge[edge unit distance=2.5ex]{6}{1}{nsubj}
\depedge[edge unit distance=2.3ex]{6}{2}{cop}
\depedge{6}{4}{poss}
\depedge{4}{3}{nn}
\depedge{4}{5}{possesive}
\wordgroup[group style={fill=cyan!40, draw=cyan, inner sep=0pt}]{1}{1}{1}{a}
\wordgroup[group style={fill=green!40, draw=green, inner sep=0pt}]{1}{2}{2}{b}
\wordgroup[group style={fill=blue!40, draw=blue, inner sep=0pt}]{1}{3}{3}{c}
\wordgroup[group style={fill=blue!40, draw=blue, inner sep=0pt}]{1}{4}{4}{d}
\wordgroup[group style={fill=violet!40, draw=violet, inner sep=0pt}]{1}{5}{5}{e}
\wordgroup[group style={fill=blue!40, draw=blue, inner sep=0pt}]{1}{6}{6}{f}
\wordgroup[group style={fill=red!40, draw=red, inner sep=0pt}]{1}{7}{7}{g}
\foreach \ind in {1,..., 7}{
\draw[blue,decorate,decoration={brace}] (\wordref{2}{\ind}.north west)-- (\wordref{2}{\ind}.north east);}
\end{dependency}
\end{document}
```

[image]